# Python doesn't see element occurrence in list

Tags: python

```
listing = [int(listing) for listing in input().split()]
summ1 = int(listing[0])
summ2 = int(listing[1])
A = [int(summ1) for summ1 in input().split()]
print(A)
B = [int(summ2) for summ2 in input().split()]
print(B)

Q = []
for i in range(int(listing[2])):
    Q.append(input().split())

L = []
for i in range(int(listing[2])):
    if Q[i][1] == 'A' and Q[i][-1] in A:
        L.append(Q[i][-1])
```

Hello, please tell me why the penultimate line of code does not work and how to fix it?

I expect that if an element from list Q is present in list A, then it should be added to list L

Comment: What is the input that you provide to this code when executed?

Comment: `A` and `B` are lists of integers.  `Q` is a list of strings.  They will never be equal.

Comment: Tim Roberts, Your answer helped, thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.